# DFS bandwidth limit ignored

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

We have two servers, one in site A and another in site B.
All servers are windows server 2012 R2.
Problem here is that on site B the server is ignoring the bandwidth limit on scheduling group.
[DFS limit 8Mbps on 12Mbps FO line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP0bK.png)

But this is being ignored and I got all ISP line connection 100% usage only for DFS. Other critical systems accessed by external users are not successfully established.

[Network usage by DFS server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K666J.png)

Does DFS service looks at another thing about limiting the bandwidth usage and for that this rule is being ignored?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this documented, but fwiw changes to the bandwidth schedules seem to stick only after restarting the DFSR service. Not sure if restarts on both source & destination are required, or if there's some way to handle with a lighter touch.

Lag related to AD polling is discussed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732278(v=ws.11)) and might be another potential culprit.